# PHP is duplicating results for first three cards of each row

Tags: php, html, css

Morning/Afternoon/Evening,

I'm terrible with PHP.  I finally got it to connect/pull the information that I wanted.

I used css to setup a grid of 3 cards.

I'm pulling Image/URL, Name, Age, State.

Right now when I load the page the every, with all three cards, hold the exact same information.

Example:

**Page:**

**Ben  Ben  Ben**

**Janna Janna Janna**

**Steven Steven Steven**

What I want:

**Page:**

**Ben Janna Steven**

Here is my PHP, and below the css.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Covid-Deaths</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
          <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f285a5a86.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="script.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>You're terrible at this</h1>
    <p>Get each picture to be unique</p>
    <?php
    //database Connection
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    // retrieving data from table accounts
    
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM test_info";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
    ?>
    <?php 
    
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           ?>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class ="card">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo $row['picture'];?>" width="80%"/></a>
            <h4><?php echo $row['names']; echo ", "; echo $row['age'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row['state']; ?></p>                
    </div>

    <div class ="card">
        <a href="<?php echo $row['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo $row['picture'];?>" width="80%"/></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row['names']; echo ", "; echo $row['age'];?></h4>
        <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row['state']; ?></p>            
    </div>

    <div class ="card">
        <a href="<?php echo $row['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo $row['picture'];?>" width="80%"/></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row['names']; echo ", "; echo $row['age'];?></h4>
        <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row['state']; ?></p>            
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
 }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 20px;
```

}

Again, I'm super new at this and can't quite figure out how to google the exact words.  Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think maybe the multiple <div class="card"> are causing the duplication, and maybe it's the css? I just removed the two extra cards and started playing with the css but I can't seem to get it to move other images over.  I think because it's displaying all of the results instead of cutting the results off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the while loop change your code as below:

```
<?php 
    
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           ?>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class ="card">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo $row['picture'];?>" width="80%"/></a>
            <h4><?php echo $row['names']; echo ", "; echo $row['age'];?></h4>
            <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row['state']; ?></p>                
    </div>

<?php
 }
    }
?>
```

Since you are having all state, name, age, image all information in one card and you are having that code in a while loop so you don't need the other cards.

```
 $query  = "SELECT * FROM test_info";
```

So if the above query result returns more than 1 row, then automatically multiple cards will be generated and information would be loaded in that.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured this was the issue.  Now if I could figure out how to get it to create more than one row down the side.  I would like 3 rows with all unique information.  I just can't seem to figure out if it's css that has to do that or the html.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

remove the extra 2 card container since your are using a loop. Try this tutorials for a better understanding on how to fetch data using php and mysql
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php